# scala spray.io test framework

Tags: scala, testing, akka, backend

I am developing a back-end solution using the scala spray.io framework with spray routing. It is my first project in scala so please be patient.

Here is the route trait:

```
trait SomeRoute extends HttpService {

  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher 

  def actorRef 

  val route = {
    post {
      path("register/") {
        ask( actorRef, CreateUser , 5.seconds).mapTo[ User ].onComplete {
          render response here
        }  
  }

}
```

Here is the Actor class

```
class SomeActor extends Actor with SomeRoute {

  def actorRefFactory = context 

  override def actorRef = this.self

}
```

I have 2 questions to you:

- Would it be a good idea to create an additional slave actor class, that will hold the "register" message and deal with user registration
- Using Specs2RouteTest gives me actorRefFactory but not the actual actor, so how can I define actorRef in this case?

  ```
  class SomeRouteSpec extends Specification with Actor with Specs2RouteTest with SomeRoute{

    def actorRefFactory = system

    override def actorRef = ???

  }
  ```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally the problem in code above that i had to use onConplete function from Future returned by CreateUser operation:

```
  path( "register/" ) {
    entity( as[ UserRegisterRequest ] ) { 
      userRegInfo => ctx => 
      registerUser( userRegInfo, ctx.complete ) 
    }
  }      

  def registerUser( 
                    userReg: UserRegisterRequest, 
                    renderResponse:RenderResponse ): Unit = {

      usersOps.createUser(userReg, 
                          DateTime.now.plus( 
                            Period.days(vcsettings.passExpired ) ) )
      .onComplete { 
       ( tryObj ) => renderResponse { 
        tryObj match { 
          case Success( user ) => VcResponse( "register_user:", 
            Map("user:" -> user.get.id ) )           

          case Failure( e ) => {
            logger < "can't register user: $userReg.toString" 
            _error_getting_user_messages_             
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

}